# How do I resize images on css list

Tags: css, css-selectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cb9b.jpg)
Please how can I resize to normal checkmark icon for a webpage on css, I'm a newbie I have no idea on how I could get the icon to look smaller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7sNU.jpg)

I don't have any idea how to resize the icon, I just know how to place the image in my list items

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work

```css
li {
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 30px;
      background-image:url("https://www.svgrepo.com/show/35641/dot.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
```